# Numbering of chemmacros reaction change to same numbering as equation

Tags: chemmacros

Is there an option of `chemmacros` to change the numbering of the `reaction` environment to the same numbering as the `equation` environment?

It looks a bit confusing if an equation follows a reaction directly and the numbering of the first is higher than the numbering of the last.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
A + B -> C + D 
\end{reaction}

\begin{reaction}
A + B -> C + D
\end{reaction}

\begin{equation}
1 + 3 = 4
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I already managed to solve this by changing the `chemmacros.sty`, but I think this is a really dirty solution.

I would prefer a solution directly in the document.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Do you want equations and reactions to share the same counter? If yes then just don't use the `reaction` environment and use `\begin{equation} \ch{A + B -> C + D} \end{equation}`.

Comment: The whole purpose of the `reaction` environment is to have *independent* numbering.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot! Much trouble easy solved! I was not aware that I can put a whole reaction in \ch!

Comment: This is (roughly speaking) what the `reaction` environment is: an `equation` with the contents wrapped in `\ch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole purpose of the `reaction` environment is to have independent numbering for displayed reactions. If you want the same numbering for displayed reactions and equations you can simply use

```
\begin{equation}
  \ch{ A + B -> C + D }
\end{equation}
```

Under the hood this is what the `reaction` environment does after all.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \ch{ A + B -> C + D }
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  \ch{ A + B -> C + D }
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  1 + 3 = 4
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you *want* to use a `reaction` environment the easiest solution would be to redefine it to just do the above (the following example contains code to make the example works with older and newer versions of `chemmacros`):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{chemmacros,environ}

% in older versions there is no \IfChemCompatibilityT
\providecommand\IfChemCompatibilityT[3]{}

% load the `reactions' module in newer versions:
\IfChemCompatibilityT{>=}{5.0}{
  \usechemmodule{reactions}
}

% redefine the environments:
\RenewEnviron{reaction}
  {\begin{equation}\expandafter\ch\expandafter{\BODY}\end{equation}}
\RenewEnviron{reaction*}
  {\begin{equation*}\expandafter\ch\expandafter{\BODY}\end{equation*}}
\RenewEnviron{reactions}
  {\begin{align}\expandafter\ch\expandafter{\BODY}\end{align}}
\RenewEnviron{reactions*}
  {\begin{align*}\expandafter\ch\expandafter{\BODY}\end{align*}}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
  A + B -> C + D
\end{reaction}

\begin{reactions}
  A + B &-> C + D \\
  E + F &<=> G
\end{reactions}

\begin{equation}
  1 + 3 = 4
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```