# how to prefix the section number to the "reaction" number?

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, chemmacros

I'm using the `chemmacros` package, its `reactions` environment, and the `article` document class:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage{upgreek, chemfig, chemmacros}

\chemsetup{modules = all}
\chemsetup[reactions]{ before-tag = \thesection. } % Adds section number to label
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{reaction}{section}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Galvanic cell}
\begin{reactions}
  Zn &-> Zn\pch[2] + 2 e\mch \label{eq:galvZnR} \\
  Cu\pch[2] + 2 e\mch &-> Cu \label{eq:galvCuR}
\end{reactions}

As seen in~\ref{eq:galvZnR} and~\ref{eq:galvCuR}...

\end{document}
```

Now I want to change the reactions label numbering to include the section number. From the chemmacros manual I found the way using the reaction/before-tag.

But the reference to the label does not include the section number. How do I fix this? I tried `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` since `reactions` only is a wrapper to align (?) but it does not work.

My next guess would be entirely redefining the reactions environment as seeen in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267804 but that seems like a rather dirty way.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you replace

```
\chemsetup[reactions]{ before-tag = \thesection. } % Adds section number to label
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{reaction}{section}
\makeatother
```

with either

```
\numberwithin{reaction}{section}
```

or

```
\counterwithin{reaction}{section}
```

The former requires loading the `amsmath` package (which your document does); the latter works even if `amsmath` isn't loaded.

---

A full MWE (minimum working example):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm, amssymb, mathtools, upgreek}
\usepackage{chemfig, chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules = all}

\numberwithin{reaction}{section}

%% Optional:
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{reaction}{reaction}{reactions}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}
\begin{reactions}
  Zn &-> Zn\pch[2] + 2 e\mch \label{eq:galvZnR} \\
  Cu\pch[2] + 2 e\mch &-> Cu \label{eq:galvCuR}
\end{reactions}

As seen in~\ref{eq:galvZnR} and~\ref{eq:galvCuR}, \dots

As seen in \cref{eq:galvZnR,eq:galvCuR}, \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\counterwithin{reaction}{section}` works even without `amsmath`.

Comment: @egreg - Thanks for this. I've updated the answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: BTW: `chemmacros` loads `mathtools` (and thus `amsmath`) anyway :)

Comment: @clemens thanks for the info. the import is a leftover from the preamble i use in every tex file where i import basic info, but i might omit it